# NSPredicate with child objects date range query?

Tags: cocoa

I am trying to filter my table with only relevant records by date range.

```
NSPredicate *currentDaypredicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"account.entries.dateCreated > %@ AND
        account.entries.dateCreated < %@ ", yesterday, tomorrow];
[accountArrayController setFilterPredicate:currentDaypredicate];
```

But of course this is wrong because I'm getting-

> [NSCFSet compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Can someone please give me a clue or example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the exception message says, you can't compare two sets, and `account.entries.dateCreated` is a set. This is most probably because `account.entries` is a set; sending a `valueForKey:` message to a set will return a set.

You need to test each date, not all of the dates at once. Try `ANY account.entries.dateCreated > %@ AND ANY account.entries.dateCreated < %@`.

(By the way, why are the objects that have accounts in an “`accountArrayController`”? Shouldn't the accounts themselves be there?)

For more on predicate format string syntax, see [that section of the Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html).

Comment: Thanks, using "@distinctUnionOfSets" and with the "ANY" solved my problem.

Comment: @ Seymour Cakes, would you please put the correct code here ? I have the same problem but using "ANY" not solved my problem.